# Doesn't work regular expression

Tags: java, android, regex

I have string regex
`"product_default_shipping_cost:\['(.*)'"`

and string

`"product_sale_price:['19.99'], product_default_shipping_cost:['1.99'], product_type:['Newegg']"`

and i want get only `1.99`.
My code :

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex_string);
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(html);

while (m.find()) {
   for (int i = 1; i <= groupCount; i++) {
      Log.w(TAG,m.group(i));
   }
}
```

But i have got `1.99'], product_type:['Newegg']`
Strange that it regular expression works perfectly in python and SWIFT but not java. I can not change this regular. What could be the issue and how to fix it?

P.S i really can't change this regular, it takes dynamic

Comment: What do you mean you can't change the regex?

Comment: regex string takes dynamic

Comment: "*Strange that it regular expression works perfectly in python and SWIFT*" are you sure? Based on this test -> [(click)](http://pythex.org/?regex=product_default_shipping_cost%3A%5C%5B%27(.*)%27&test_string=product_sale_price%3A%5B%2719.99%27%5D%2C%20product_default_shipping_cost%3A%5B%271.99%27%5D%2C%20product_type%3A%5B%27Newegg%27%5D&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0) doesn't seem to be working as you described. Anyway if you can't change your regex you can't fix your problem because `.*` by default is greedy.

Comment: I'd consider writing a trivial parser instead of using regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing it to this:

```
product_default_shipping_cost:\['(.*?)'
```

`.*?` is lazy and will only try to match up to the first `'`

Comment: I can't change, this string gets dynamic

Comment: Then what do expect us to do for you? The regex is wrong. Your best bet is try to fake it 'till you make it and split the string on `,`

Answer (score 2):

`.*` will match as many characters as possible (is "greedy").

You can either use non-gready `.*?`, or limit what can be matched: `[^']*`.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a `greedy` regex `.*`, try using a *non greedy*, also know as `lazy`, by appending a `?`, i.e.:

```
product_default_shipping_cost:\['(.*?)'\]
```

---

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("product_default_shipping_cost:\['(.*?)'\]");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(html);

while (m.find()) {
   for (int i = 1; i <= groupCount; i++) {
      Log.w(TAG,m.group(i));
   }
}
```

---

**DEMO**

https://regex101.com/r/aF1hI6/1

---

Nice explanation about [greedy and lazy regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2301298/797495)